# Iphone splash screen removal in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my project summary, I dropped an image in Launch Images place. Which started shown as splash screen when application starts.

Now I have deleted it and there is no Default.png in my project folder. But still that image is being shown as splash screen.

How I can remove it?

Any idea .... ?

Comment: I have reset the iOS Simultor many times, but its not going. What else  should I clean ?

Comment: As in, clean the project. Try `cmd`+`shift`+`K`, then build again.

Comment: thanx Mac, please update this comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, all you need do is clean the project, then rebuild.

To clean the project, simply press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Then, build as normal.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried doing a clean build?
or deleting the app from the device/simulator and re-deploying it?

Answer (score 1):

To illoGicalError

doing clean and Build will not remove it.

You need to delete the application on your simulator ,then run your application again... It will work...

Answer (score 0):

Press `Command+K` then build and run. This will remove all unused images from your build.
You can also get to this command from the `project` menu bar

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .app from the Products folder in your Xcode sidebar.

But generally, don't worry - Xcode just likes to cache things like this - if you build for the device then it won't be there.